# Nested table in JQuery Datatable: TypeError: C is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am simply trying to show the table using JQuery Datatable. 
It worked fine until I added nested table.

Here is the table:

```
<table id="owner_report" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Owner Name</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Call Date</th>
                            <th>Proposal Number </th>
                            <th>Proposal Date </th>
                            <th>Quotation Number </th>
                            <th>Quotation Date </th>
                            <th>From Date</th>
                            <th>To Date</th>
                            <th>Payment Date</th>
                            <th>Cheque Number</th>
                            <th>Amount</th>
                            <th>Remarks</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Owner Name</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Call Date</th>
                            <th>Proposal Number </th>
                            <th>Proposal Date </th>
                            <th>Quotation Number </th>
                            <th>Quotation Date </th>
                            <th>From Date</th>
                            <th>To Date</th>
                            <th>Payment Date</th>
                            <th>Cheque Number</th>
                            <th>Amount</th>
                            <th>Remarks</th>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                        if(!empty($owners_array)) {
                            foreach($owners_array as $ownersReport) {
                                $ownersRecord = $ownersReport;
                                $ownersDetailList = get_post_meta($ownersRecord->ID, 'machineOwnerArray', true);
                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><?php echo $ownersDetailList['ownerName'];?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $ownersDetailList['status'];?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $ownersDetailList['callDate'];?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $ownersDetailList['proposalNumber'];?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $ownersDetailList['proposalDate'];?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $ownersDetailList['quotationNumber'];?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $ownersDetailList['quotationDate'];?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $ownersDetailList['fromDate'];?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $ownersDetailList['toDate'];?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $ownersDetailList['paymentDate'];?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $ownersDetailList['chequeNumber'];?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $ownersDetailList['amount'];?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $ownersDetailList['remarks'];?></td>
                                    <td>
                                        **<table>
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr> 
                                                    <th> just testing </th>
                                                    <th> just testing </th>
                                                    <th> just testing </th>
                                                    <th> just testing </th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>
                                                <tr> 
                                                    <td> just testing </td>
                                                    <td> just testing </td>
                                                    <td> just testing </td>
                                                    <td> just testing </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                       </table>**
                                    </td>
                                </tr><?php
                            }
                        }
                        wp_reset_postdata();
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

No fancy things in Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
           var table=$('#owner_report').DataTable();

}
```

Also if there any other way I could add The second table inside a row which will only be visible on clicking of the row.

Comment: Your no of columns are not match with header and footer

Comment: LOL. How stupid mistake. I checked that 10 times but only for inner table.  Thank you.

Comment: glad if getting upvote on that comment

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60222904/9418590